# Unexpected Null value while getting bytes from readStream of file picker | Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, null, filepicker, bytestream

i have tried multiple solutions but stuck to solve how do i get full image bytes which is only possible by readStream.listen but unable to solve.

```
    Future<Uint8List> pickImage()async {
  List<int> bytes = [];
 var result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
    dialogTitle: "Please Choose Image File",
    withReadStream: true,
    type: FileType.custom,
    allowedExtensions: ["jpg", "png", "jpeg", "gif", "bmp"],
  );


  return Uint8List.fromList(await result!.files.first.readStream!.first);
}
```

This is first try to get bytes without getting percentage received chunks but got null after a sec.

```
    Future<Uint8List> pickImage()async {
  List<int> bytes = [];
  FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
    dialogTitle: "Please Choose Image File",
    withReadStream: true,
    type: FileType.custom,
    allowedExtensions: ["jpg", "png", "jpeg", "gif", "bmp"],
  ).then((result) {
    if (result != null) {
      result.files.first.readStream!.listen((event) {
        bytes.addAll(event);
        print((Uint8List
            .fromList(bytes)
            .lengthInBytes /
            result.files.first.size) *
            100);
      });
      print(result.files.first.name);
      print(result.files.first.size);
    }
  });

  return Uint8List.fromList(bytes);
}
```

This is 2nd try to get bytes with %age received which i actually need but this cannot wait for listening all chunks of bytes and return the object

call of function

```
controller.cropImageWeb(await pickImage(),);
```

i also tried to use ImagePicker() which is working 100% on web but the issue is i cannot get the name of file size before reading file and %age of completion . so i avoid to use it

**i want not to return before completely getting file via readStream.listen**

Comment: so you have `Stream<Uint8List> inputStream` and what exactly do you want to do with that `Stream`? do you want to get all the bytes from that `Stream`?

Comment: @pskink yes i want all the bytes bcoz i have to send it to Multipart request

Comment: you don't need all the bytes, see [MultipartFile](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartFile/MultipartFile.html) constructor

Comment: @pskink Got your point.

Comment: @pskink but i also need bytes to send it to an other widget image cropper what should i do for that?

Comment: I have no idea what "widget image cropper" you are talking about